# VBA's .Find() throws "Unable to get the Find property of the Range class"

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub FindTest()
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim target As Integer

    target = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, "A")

    result = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10:A21").Find(What:=target,_
    LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=byRows).Row

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells("D7") = result 
End Sub
```

Another project using the .Find() was producing an error.  Isolating the code needed to make a .Find() work is what has brought me to the above example.

Running the above code results in the error message below, at the line starting with the **result = ...** line where the .Find() is located.

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Unable to get the Find property of the Range class

I have replaced the .Range() with .Cells() with no change in the error message.
Copy/pasting code using .Find() to determine the last used row in a worksheet that is available in other questions on StackExchange causes no errors. Example below:

```
Dim lastUsedRow as Integer
lastUsedRow = Worksheets("Receiving Worksheet").Cells.Find(What:="*",_
SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

Comment: I believe the 'target' variable must be the actual value of the cell - not the cell itself. ie: target = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, "A").value

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon `.Value` is the default property of `Cells()`.

Comment: what is the value of `target` when it breaks?

Comment: My sample 'search list' and 'target' are whole numbers.  'Search list' is 1 ~ 12 and the target is 1.  @ScottCraner

Comment: Did you try @EganWolf answer?  He seems to have found the issue with that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `SearchOrder:=byRows` => `SearchOrder:=xlByRows`
2. Place space before `_` at the end of first line

Comment: Spaces and underscores are not in my actual code, they are only added here in this forum to eliminate the need for using the scroll bar.  xlbyRows corrected and in line 10 .Cells("D7") was changed to .Cells(7, "D").  No error is thrown but the result is incorrect.  I changed the .Range("A10:A21") to .Range("A9:A21") as it looks like the search range ignores the first cell in the search range.  Thanks for the help everybody.

Comment: Yes, `Find()` ignores first cell. More info in [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx), section _Parameters_ -> _After_. You can probably workaround this by setting the last cell of your range as value for `After`.